# What's the best way to create the combined fields in Elastic Search?

Tags: elasticsearch

For example, I have fields `street`, `city`, `state`, `continent`, `planet`.

There is situation when I should search by combination of two fields `street` and `city`, and there is situation when  I should search by combination of all fields: `street`, `city`, `state`, `continent`, `planet`.

The search should be fuzzy, support morphology and etc.

I can store only two fields `short_address` and `full_address`, but index become inadequate heavy in this case, so I assume there should be way to use the fact, that that fields are only the combination of same fields.

What I have tried:

1. Runtime fields. A runtime field don't support the type `text` only `keyword`.
2. Combined fields. A combined field don't support fuzziness.